# case in a switch statement in C

Tags: c, switch-statement

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main(){
     char operator;
     double a, b;

     printf("enter an operand(+,-,*,/)");
     scanf("%c",&operator);
     printf("enter two operands");
     scanf("%lf %lf",&a,&b);

     switch(operator){
       case '+': printf("%lf is the output of a & b",(a+b)); break;
       case '-': printf("%lf is the output of a & b",(a-b)); break;
       case '*': printf("%lf is the output of a & b",(a*b)); break;
       case '/': printf("%lf is the output of a & b",(a/b)); break;
    }
}
```

I know that only an integer is allowed after a case. I also know that any character written inside single inverted commas writtens an ascii interger.

In this the argument inside the switch statement is a character,
`switch(operator);`.

How will that equate with an integer inside the case?
`case '+':`

Comment: _Characters_ are integers.  With ASCII, `'+'` has integer value 43.

Answer (score 3):

The condition in the `switch`-statement needs not to be type `int` exactly but "any expression of integer type (char, signed or unsigned integer, or enumeration)" (cf., for example, [switch statement documentation at cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/switch)). So using variable `operator` of type `char` as condition in the `switch`-statement is ok.

The constant expressions in each `case:`-label are converted to the promoted type of expression (`char` in your case) and the result of evaluating the condition is then compared with the (converted) value of the expression. A constant expression of type char like `'+'`, `'-'` is therefore OK, too.

In the end, the promoted type of the condition is `char`, each constant in your `case:`-statements is of type `char`, and therefore `char` is compared with `char`.

Note that the char-"value" of constant `'+'` is it's 8 bit ASCII-value, which is `43`. Also, if one enters `+` in the console when using `scanf("%c",&operator)`, the "value" of `operator` will be the 8 bit ASCII-value of `+`, too, i.e. `43`. In this case, the switch-statement will compare 8 bit `43` with 8 bit `43`...

Hope it helps.

Comment: Quoting from a C++ site for a C question is of limited help.  'Contextually implicitly convertible' isn't remotely related to the wording or specification in the C standard!

Comment: Sure this compiles in C?  The error I get is "error: case label does not reduce to an integer constant"

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: right, thanks. While answering the question I switched to C++ in mind, while still writing and testing the code in a C-environment. Awesome.

Comment: @chux: Though being useless now (since the answer for C differs from the former one for C++), the former code actually compiled using LLVM 8.0 with -std=C99.

Comment: One remaining C++-ism, each constant in OP's case is of type int, not char. (And promoted char is also int, so that matches)

Answer (score 0):

`char` is just the 8 bit (mostly) integer

so `case '+':` is an equivalent of the `to case 43:` as 43 is the ascii code of '+'

Comment: That is what my question is, how can we equate a characer i.e, the orerator parameter inside switch to an integer inside case which is equivalent to 43 for '+'

Comment: `switch(operator)` - if `operator` is 43 - the `case '+':` will be chosen. Both are integer types.